# Finding out sources of connections to MongoDB cluster

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

The "Real Time Metrics" panel of my MongoDB Atlas cluster, shows 36 connections, even though I terminated all server apps that were supposed to be connected to it. Currently nothing should be connected to it, but I still see those 36 connections. I tried pausing the cluster and then resuming it - the connections came back. Is there any way for me to find out where are they coming from? OR, terminating all connections.

Answer (score 2):

Each connection is supposed to provide with it what is called "app metadata". This is supposed to always include:

- The driver identifier (e.g. pymongo 1.2.3)
- The platform of the client (e.g. linux amd64)

Additionally, you can provide your own information to be sent as part of client metadata which you can use to identify your application. See e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-create-client/ `:app_name` option.

Atlas has internal processes that connect to cluster nodes and cluster nodes communicate with each other also. All of these add to connection count seen on each node.

To figure out where connections are coming from:

1. Read the server logs (which you have to download first) to obtain the client metadata sent with each connection.
2. Hopefully this will provide enough clues to identify cluster to cluster connections. You should also be able to tell those by source IPs which you should be able to dig out of cluster configuration.
3. Atlas connections should be using either Go or Java drivers, if you don't use those in your own applications this would be an easy way of telling those apart.
4. Add app name to all of your application connections to eliminate those from the unknown ones.

There is no facility provided by MongoDB server to terminate connections from clients. You can kill operations and sessions but connections used for those operations would remain until the clients close them. When clients close connections depends on the particular driver used and connection pool settings, see e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-create-client/#connection-pooling.